# Remove DTS packages from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, dts

What is the easiest way to remove multiple DTS packages from SQL Server 2008?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using DTS (not SSIS) the packages are stored on the SQL server, the fastest way to remove them is to delete them directly from where they are held - msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages.

Sysdtspackages contains multiple versions of each package which has been edited and saved.

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages
```

will show you the contents of the table.

```
DELETE 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages
WHERE name in ('package1','package2',etc)
```

will remove the packages you name.